# Can't seem to get any of several examples of FORM INLINE to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried 3 different examples of INLINE forms without success.  At this point I can only suspect it's something in the CSS file but I can't figure it out.  Every attempt has resulted in the same UI as depicted in the image below.

I trying to get the four elements of the form at the top to display inline with placeholders but no labels and be able to assign individual widths for each input.

I'm in the process of expanding my limited experience with CSS and JS so please be explicit.

```
<html>
<head>
    <META charset="utf-8">
    <META NAME="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <TITLE>OldSchool Lister</TITLE>
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="Griffin Web Design &#174;">
    <META NAME="Copyright" CONTENT="&#169; 2021 Griffin Web Design">
    <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="Old School Lister (Grocery List et al)">
    <META NAME="KeyWords" CONTENT="OldSchool, Old School, Lists, Lister, Grocery, Groceries">
    <META NAME="Location" CONTENT="http://dangriffin.info/lister/">
    <META NAME="Created" CONTENT="07/01/2022">
    <LINK rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="grocery.css">
</head>

<BODY BACKGROUND="LegalPad.gif">
    <TABLE CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0>
        <TR>
            <TD WIDTH="75" VALIGN="top">
                <IMG SRC="OldSchoolIcon.png" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50" ALT="">
            </TD>
            <TD>
                <IMG SRC="OldSchoolBanner.gif" WIDTH="280" HEIGHT="52" ALT=""><BR>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <BR>

    <main>
        <form role="form">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item-input" placeholder="Item">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity-input" placeholder="Qty">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="uom-input" placeholder="UoM">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">+</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="lists">
            <ul id="shopping-list"></ul>

            <p class="list__label">Cart <span class="quantity" id="bought-num"></span></p>
            <ul id="bought-list"></ul>
        </div>
    </main>

    <div class="push"></div>
    </div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<!-- Lodash JS - MIN finds the minimum value of an array -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<!-- Backbone JS - Listens for changes and renders UL -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js'></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS formatting library  v3.3.7 -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- All of the standard js for this app  -->
<SCRIPT SRC="./grocery.js"></SCRIPT>

</body>
</html>

    

form {
        width : inherit;
    }
    label {
        display     : inline;
        line-height : 1.5em;
    }
    input {        /* All input boxes */
        width   : inherit;
        padding : .25em;
    }
    .delete,
        button {
        color            : white;
        background-color : #FF0000;
    }

    button {                 /* ADD button */
        border  : 5;
        padding : .25em;
        width   : inherit;
        margin  : 0.75em 0;
    }

    #bought-list li:before, #shopping-list li:before {
        content         : "";
        display         : inline;
        background-size : 100%;
        height          : 0.9em;
        width           : 1em;
        margin-right    : 0.3em;
    }

    .row > div {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #shopping-list li:before {
        background-image: url("./checkmark2.svg");
    }

    #bought-list li:before {
        background-image: url("./checkmark.svg");
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    li {
        color: #004A55;
        padding: 0.25em;
        margin: 0em 0;
        position: relative;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }

    .quantity {
        color: #004A55;                 /* All numbers */
    }

    .quantity:before {                  /* All numbers */
        content: "(";
    }

    .quantity:after {                   /* All numbers */
        content: ")";
    }

    .delete {
        float: right;
        padding: inherit;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .delete:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    #bought-list li {
        background-color: #F6F6F6;
    }

    #bought-list li .quantity {
        color: #666666;
    }

    .list__label {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ff0303;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #004A55;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

There is also a .js file I can post if you feel it necessary.

[Original post output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQkni.png)

[Output after suggested changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLgSp.jpg)

Comment: a `</div>` is missing. you need to use css `display: inline-block;`

Comment: you haven't shown us any of the CSS for the element `<div class="form-group col-xs-4">`. that div, without modifying via CSS, will display as a block (`display: block`) that fills 100% of parent width.

Comment: Those look like boostrap classes. Are you using bootstrap? Have you included it?

Comment: Yes, I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: @Mister Jojo where is the missing </div> supposed to go.  Is it the "<div class="row">" supposed to have a </div> immediately after it?

Comment: make a simple count, there are 5 opening div tags and only 4 closing ones. Never rely on code interpreters to properly close your tags

Comment: there is is probably 20 bootstrap versions. with one is yours ?

Comment: @Aigaruto I have added ".row > div { display: inline-block; }" to the CSS file at the position you have.  But my display does not match the "Run code snippet" result... which is EXACTLY what I wanted.  There is additional CSS code beyond what you have posted, which is all that showed of the entire CSS file that I (thought) I had posted.  Maybe something there is interfering?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment: Please also describe what the problem actually is. What is happening that shouldn't? What isn't happening that should? Adding Boostrap to your code produces a result similar to what you described, but not what is in your image: https://jsfiddle.net/018eqrd6/

Comment: How do you add a chunk of code to a Comment?

Comment: @Jon P When I added the recommended changes to my files I get the FORM just as I wanted.  However, it moved the UL list to the top with the FORM below.  And when I added the </div> to the end of "<div class="row">" everything went back to the example image I furnished.

Comment: There's no image???  How do I put an image in a Comment?

Comment: What `UL` ? There's no `UL` in your code. You may be suffering from an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @dqhendricks The "<div class="form-group col-xs-4">" is in the rest of the CSS file that wasn't included in the original question that I pasted.  I pasted the whole file but only part of it made it into the original question.

Comment: @Jon P The UL is referenced in the lower part of the CSS file that didn't make it into the original post.

Comment: Don't add code or images to comments [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73187251/edit) your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you need to use display: inline-block
Since I don't see the css for "form-group col-xs-4" and others I added the display to all the divs in the .row class.

```css
    form {
      width : inherit;
      }
    label {
      display     : inline;
      line-height : 1.5em;
      }
    input {        /* All input boxes */
      width   : inherit;
      padding : .25em;
      }
    .delete,
    button {
      color            : white;
      background-color : #FF0000;
      }
    button {                 /* ADD button */
      border  : 5;
      padding : .25em;
      width   : inherit;
      margin  : 0.75em 0;
      }
    #bought-list li:before,
    #shopping-list li:before {
      content         : "";
      display         : inline-block;
      background-size : 100%;
      height          : 0.9em;
      width           : 1em;
      margin-right    : 0.3em;
      }
    
    .row > div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
        <form role="form" class="form-inline">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
          <label>Item</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item-input" placeholder="Item">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
          <label>Qty</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity-input" placeholder="Qty">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
          <label>UoM</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="uom-input" placeholder="UoM">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">+</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```